# Pulling without merging

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to make a crontab that pulls and makes a repository every day for me, but whenever i do that and the repository merges the crontab gets stuck.
Is there a way to pull without prompting a merge and without deleting my code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. What does "make a repository every day for me"? If you're pulling you already have a repository. Do you mean you're updating the working folder? Also, what do you mean by "repository merges"? Do you mean that you're in fact not only pulling, but also updating, and that the update process tries to merge in the changeset you're updating to into the changes you've applied in your working folder? Please elaborate what you mean here.

Comment: It's literally the make command

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to pull without prompting a merge

Just `hg pull` by itself does not merge, nor does it ask the user for anything.  The local repository will be added to, but the local working directory will not be touched.  Nothing will be deleted.

If your `.hgrc` file is using a `[defaults]` section, you might be silently adding the -u/--update option without realizing it.  That option tries to automatically do an update.  If that's the case, then don't use defaults sections.

If this doesn't answer your question, then show us *exactly* what commands your cron entry is running, what the output is, where it "gets stuck" (is SSH asking for authentication credentials?), and which part you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to how do you pull without merging is you `hg fetch` which gets the new remote changesets but doesn't update any files in your working directory.  It sounds like what you're really asking though is "how do I update to tip and throw away any local changes?".  If that's what you're going for you'd do:

```
hg fetch # gets new changesets
hg update --clean  # update to latest files THROWING AWAY LOCAL CHANGES
```

Is that what you're going for?

Comment: No. What i want is to discard repository changes that aren't solved automatically. I want to keep mine.

Comment: Okay, you update your question to ask that and I'll update my answer w/ how to do it. :)